# Siri shortcut for external keyboard

Tags: siri

I have an external bluetooth keyboard attached to my macbook pro. I don't have function "fn" key on my external keyboard. The shortcut to call siri is `fn + space`. How am I supposed to call Siri now?

Also I don't wish to change this shortcut.

Comment: If you don't want to change the shortcut, then you'll have to change the keyboard.

Comment: You could use a keyboard remapping program to map the Fn key to an available key on your bluetooth keyboard, although at that point you might as well just change the shortcut.